# Given a table and some fixed values in Excel, how to create a repeated pattern? (such as in picture)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have table with some item names and their values across months. I want to create a repeated pattern where names remain but values change according to month. Basically, there is a data for 12 months and the number of rows in the Names table and Months table changes.

[image: given and desired result]

I have used different formulas for every column to reach the result: VSTACK to stack data in the 2nd range, REPEAT to repeat the given Code, increment function to increment month no. every n row and LET function to repeat n times the Names. But I think there is a more effective way to do it, i.e. by combining all of it into one formula so that it eventually gives the result. Are there any ways?

Comment: What is the purpose of *Repeat* since by the looks of it, the data is 'repeated' as many times as there are columns in the 2nd range? Try to explain by e.g. sharing the result for `Repeats = 5`. Also, share the formulas you have tried and some sample data as text.

Comment: @VBasic2008 well, yes, it is repeated as many times as there are columns in the 2nd range. Basically I have used different formulas for every column to reach the result: VSTACK to stack data in the 2nd range, REPEAT to repeat the given Code, increment function to increment month no. every n row and LET function to repeat n times the Names. But I think there is a more effective way to do it, i.e. by combining all of it into one formula so that it eventually gives the result. Are there any ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LET(a,B5:D8,
     b,F5:H8,
HSTACK(
       REDUCE(a,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(b)-1),LAMBDA(r,x,VSTACK(r,a))),
       INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)*COLUMNS(b),,1,1/ROWS(a))),
       TOCOL(b,,1)))
```

The `Reduce` part stacks `a` the number of columns present in `b` (start value is the range, so stack columns -1).

This gets stacked with a `tocol` of `b`.

Edit: I missed out on the first column:

```
=LET(a,B5:D9,
     b,F5:H9,
     c,B2,
IFERROR(
        HSTACK(c,
               REDUCE(a,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(b)-1),LAMBDA(r,x,VSTACK(r,a))),
               INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)*COLUMNS(b),,1,1/ROWS(a))),
               TOCOL(b,,1)),
        c))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked with the example image above. What if the range of Names and Months change? Like there could be more rows in these tables. Also, can we put into this formula the month no. column as shown in the image?

Comment: Missed that, see edit.

Comment: Wow, it worked well! What if the number of rows in two given tables change?

Comment: Have you checked yourself?

Answer (score 1):

### Generate Range Repeats

[image]

```
=LET(cValue,B2,nData,B5:D8,mData,F5:H8,
    ncc,COLUMNS(nData),mcc,COLUMNS(mData),
    rc,ROWS(nData),tr,rc*mcc,
    c,INDEX(cValue,SEQUENCE(tr,,1,0)),
    s,SEQUENCE(tr)-1,rs,MOD(s,rc)+1,
    ncs,SEQUENCE(,ncc),
    n,INDEX(nData,rs,ncs),
    mcs,INT(s/rc)+1,
    m,INDEX(mData,rs,mcs),
    dr,HSTACK(c,n,mcs,m),
dr)
```

- If you'd add the data to Excel tables, you could use structured references:

  ```
  ... nData,Table1,mData,Table2,...
  ```

  and add more rows and columns and the formula would still work.

[image]

Comment: Sir you have not used the cell for the n times of repeat

Comment: The number of columns in the second range determines the number of repeats `... mcc,COLUMNS(mData),...` (*Months Columns Count*).